# Eclipse modifies shared ant-launch configuration storing last launched tag in it

Tags: eclipse, ant

In Eclipse 3.8 I need to run my build.xml ant script within the workspace JRE. So I altered my ant launch configuration choosing

- "Run in the same JRE as the workspace"

in the JRE tag, stored the launch configuration in the shared file (on the common tab) and then commited the .launch file to the repository. Now all developers sharing this configuration and the build.xml script work correctly.

My problem is, that each time someone runs different targets from my build.xml, the eclipse alters the .launch configuration adding/modifing the last runned target. Then the modification popups in the commit window, that irritates developers and produces merge conflicts, if commited.

The change to .launch file is:

```
...
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_ANT_TARGETS" value="build,"/>
...
```

My question is, how can I prevent Eclipse from modifing my .launch configuration files?

Thank you!

PS
Source code management is IBM Synergy

Comment: Would have been interested in this too, but obviously this is not a burning issue for the rest of the world. Some checkbox "do not store last executed target" would be nice.